# Small resistor value for a differentiator

Tags: resistors

I’m having a hard time understanding “pick a resistor value that is small enough so dVout/dt << dVin/dt” for a differentiator. I’m graphing 5 V DC supplied to this circuit, and even at 1M ohm and 1pF, the voltage across the capacitor reaches Vin in 10us. I don’t experiment with AC & ”high speed” yet

I get how a small resistor (R2) connected to another resistor (R1) in series, would cause a large portion of the supplied voltage to be across (R1). I’m trying to connect that to this technique and I need help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your differentiator circuit can also be thought of as a High Pass Filter. This might be a little easier to understand.

There is a Corner Frequency for the High Pass Filter which is;
F  =  1 / (2 Pi R C)

At the Corner Freq  R = Xc  where Xc = 1 / (2 Pi F C)

At frequencies below the Corner Freq. the response is increasing at 6 db/octave.

As long as there is this increasing response then the circuit is acting like a Differentiator.

Do you use Spice? Such as LTSpice?

It is free and pretty easy to use.

You can put your circuit in there and work with it.

For your original question, just pick a resistor, say 1000 ohms and then compute a capacitor using the above 2 formulas, such that the response is always changing at +6db/octave in the region where you want to "differentiate a signal".

If you haven't used Spice (such as LTSpice), I think you might find it a lot of fun and in the future, indispensable.

Here is a link for Windows version of LTSpice;
[LTSpice for Windows CLICK HERE](https://ltspice-iv.en.lo4d.com/windows)

All the Best,
xstack